# Using the sourcecodepro font with Beamer listings

Tags: beamer, fonts, listings

I would like to use the `sourcecodepro` package to typeset source code in `Beamer`. The following code gives the same fonts, regardless whether `sourcecodepro` is loaded or not.
I would like to stick to `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\frame[containsverbatim]{
\frametitle{Test}
\framesubtitle{Systeme}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello, this is a
    \item test for the sourcecodepro
    \item Right now it does not work
\end{itemize}

\begin{lstlisting}
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loading the `sourcecodepro` package makes Source Code Pro the default *typewriter* font of the document. However, by default, the `listings` package uses the document's default *roman* family.

Therefore, after loading `sourcecodepro`, you still need to tell `listings` that you want to typeset your code in typewriter font:

```
basicstyle = \ttfamily
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\frame[containsverbatim]{
\frametitle{Test}
\framesubtitle{Systeme}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello, this is a
    \item test for the sourcecodepro
    \item Right now it does not work
\end{itemize}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily] % <--- here
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
\end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```